# Get database name mongoDB with bash script

Tags: mongodb, bash

I want to automate my mongo backup process with bash. My plan is to get all database name on mongo and store to a file, lets called "database-name.txt". Then I want to dump the database with for loop from that file and save the backup to other directory.

the problem:

- everytime I connect mongo shell, it would show information like this

```
MongoDB shell version v5.0.9
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("some-random-string") }
MongoDB server version: 5.0.9
================
Warning: the "mongo" shell has been superseded by "mongosh",
which delivers improved usability and compatibility.The "mongo" shell has been deprecated and will be removed in
an upcoming release.
For installation instructions, see
https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/install/
================
admin      0.000GB
config     0.000GB
local      0.000GB
database1  0.000GB
database2  0.000GB
bye
```

I dont need this information and just want to save my database name. I've search for all possibility but still not get it done. How I supposed to do it?

Comment: `mongo --quiet` doesn't print the connection process details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `mongo --quiet`

However, it still prints the deprecation warning. You get rid of it in combination with `--eval` but then command `show dbs` is not possible

```
mongo --quiet --eval 'show dbs'

uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell eval):1:5
exiting with code -4
```

So, final solution is [Mongo.getDBNames()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Mongo.getDBNames/) or [listDatabases](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/)

```
mongo --quiet --eval "db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } ).databases.map(x => x.name).join('\n')" > database-name.txt

mongo --quiet --eval "db.getMongo().getDBNames().join('\n')" > database-name.txt
```

should return file of

```
admin 
config 
local 
database1 
database2
```

Comment: Woah, Thank you! It just the way I want! little additional question, how about if I want to exclude the default db like admin? Is it possible to add find function on the query above?

Comment: Yes, try `databases.map(x => x.name).filter( x => x != 'admin')` or `filter(x => !Array('admin', 'local', 'config').includes(x))` Command `listDatabases` also provides filter option

Comment: The filter works great with 1 value but it caught an error with array. the terminal says `bash: !Array: event not found`. I'm running with this query `mongo --quiet --eval "db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } ).databases.map(x => x.name).filter(x => !Array('admin', 'local', 'config').includes(x)).join('\n')" > database-name.txt`. Am I missed something?

Comment: Use different quotes: `--eval 'db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } ).databases.map(x => x.name).filter(x => !Array("admin", "local", "config").includes(x)).join("\n")'` or `'db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1} ).databases.map(x => x.name).filter( x => '\!' Array("admin", "local", "config").includes(x)).join("\n")'`